# Pass variable to getElementById

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have multiple tables which are generated by loop and each table have different ids. Like (table1,table2,table3 and so on.)
I want to pass these id to getElementById function using jquery each function.
Here is my code

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $('.table', this).each(function (index, element) {
        tnames = $(element).attr('id');

        //alert(tnames)
        var elem5 = document.getElementById(tnames);
        alert(elem5);

    });
});
```

tnames alert fine. but when i pass tname to `getElementById` function it return null or object. I want it should return ids as returning `alert(tname)`;

Any help and suggestions. Please?

Comment: Please show some HTML. And note that IDs must be unique

Comment: You just need to use `element` i.e. `var elem5 = $(element);`

Comment: Something like this

HTML CODE:-
<table id="table1"></table>
<table id="table2"></table>
<table id="table3"></table>

JQUERY:-
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.table', this).each(function(index, element) {
      tnames = $(element).attr('id'); //tname saving all tables id like table1,table2, table3

  var elem5 = document.getElementById(tnames);  //Here I want to pass all id to elem5 variable one by one using getelementbyid

  alert(elem5);
 
    });
 });
</script>

But elem5 return nothing. You get what i want?

Comment: @FarrukhZaman What is your end goal here? You already have a reference to the element you're trying to access in the value `element`. You shouldn't need to get the element again through document.getElementById.

Comment: @SeanCogan exactly. I smell an X/Y problem here.

Comment: Ok in easy words i am using this code

$(document).ready(function(){
 $('.table', this).each(function(index, element) {
     // tnames = $(element).attr('id');
  // console.log(tnames);
    var elem5 = document.getElementById($(element).attr('id'));
    alert(elem5);
    });
 });


It is returning me [object HTMLTableElement]. I want it should return ids.

Comment: But that's my point. You already have the ID of the HTML Element you're trying to return. If you just do `alert($(element).attr('id'));`, it will alert the ID of the current HTML element. You're doing double work to use the ID from the element to get the element again to get it's ID again.

Answer (score 1):

I hope following code will help you to find an element's id.
Following code will alert table id.

```
$("document").ready(function () {           
        var tableid= $('table').attr('id');

        var element = document.getElementById(tableid);
        alert(element.id);

});
```

Comment: No need to do a getElementById to get the ID

Comment: But the questioner wants to pass table id to the getElemetById() function. That's why I've use that function. Otherwise I've got the element id using attr('id').

Comment: I know. OP needs to ask what he actually needs and not what he thinks he needs

Answer (score 1):

If you for sure have

```
<table class="table" id="table1"></table>
<table class="table" id="table2"></table>
<table class="table" id="table3"></table>
```

Then you can do

```
$(function () {
  $('.table').each(function () {
    console.log(this.id); // or the more verbose $(this).attr("id");
  });
});
```

Full example below:

```js
$(function() {
  $('.table').each(function() {
 
    var tableID = this.id; // here is the ID

    console.log(tableID); 


    // if you need the table itself
    var elem5 = $(this).get(0); // get the DOM table from jQuery
    console.log("using jQuery get",elem5);

    elem5 = document.getElementById(tableID); // get the DOM table using DOM access
    console.log("using getElementById",elem5);
  
   
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table" id="table1"><tr><td>Table1</td></tr></table>
<table class="table" id="table2"><tr><td>Table2</td></tr></table>
<table class="table" id="table3"><tr><td>Table3</td></tr></table>
```

Comment: I don't want content. innerHTML return content. I need id attributes value. like it should return table1, table2, table3.

Comment: I got id man. but i can't pass that id to getElementById function. how i can pass that?

Comment: Yes you can. You have some other problem. We cannot help you unless we know your setup and why you are so desperate to use document.getElementById

Answer (score 0):

Stick with jquery

```
 var elem5 = $("#"+tnames);
 alert(elem5.html());
```

Comment: No i want to pass it getElementById. Because i am using jspdf library which create pdf from html. For that i need to pass table id to getElementById.

Comment: then do `$("#"+tnames)[0]`

Comment: No its returning content with in table id. I need it should return id attribute.

Comment: you mean  `elem5  = "#"+tnames`